# Transforming a summation of a squared function with a variable upper limit. "Counting up rather than down?"

Tags: algorithm

I am in an algorithms class and my teacher attempted to show me a method of simplifying a summation, but I don't quite get it.

The summation in question is: (not sure how to write it with fancy symbols)

The Summation of *(n-2i)^2* from i=1 to ((n/2) - 1)

Now, I could foil it out and use the summation rules on each part of the resulting equation, but my instructor told me that I could simplify the summation into this:

The summation of *(2i)^2* from *i=1* to *((n-2)/2)*

He said that by "counting up" you could eliminate the function squared in the original. And 'n' being a constant within the summation apparently helps make this transformation possible? Hope this makes some sense. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the original summation with **j** in place of i.  Reverse the order of the summation, so that it's `j = (n/2 - 1) down to 1`

Then make the substitution **i = n-j**.

Now, what are the upper and lower limits?  What is the new expression?

Is that enough to move you along?